# insert to database error on heroku but worked locally, ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku

I have 2 models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :micro_posts, :dependent => :destroy
  ..
  def add_post(post)
    self.micro_posts << post
  end

class MicroPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
```

and the migration:

```
class CreateMicroPosts < <ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :micro_posts do |t| 
    ...
```

And when I called add_post on heroku server, I got an error:

```
2012-02-06T02:59:58+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0): INSERT INTO "micro_posts" ("created_at", "description", "pub_date", "tag", "title", "updated_at", "url", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"):
2012-02-06T02:59:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:25:in `add_post'
```

But the wired thing is, it worked on my computer. My OS info:

```
ubuntu 10.04
ruby 1.9.3p0
rails 3.1.3
postgresql 8.4.10
```

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code at a first glance. I do however note that you're running PostgreSQL 8.4 as where Heroku is running at 9.0.4 (or even 9.1). Try upgrading your Postgres and see if you can reproduce the error locally. This will give you more detailed logging.

Comment: thank you. i'll upgrade it and try.

Comment: NO. I upgrade postgresql to 9.1.2 (build from source), and it worked locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem, but still do not know why.

After some trying in heroku console (heroku run console), I found the error is not caused by my add_post method. Actually it was caused by my MicroPost.new:

```
post = MicroPost.new(..., :pub_date => rss_item.pubDate)
```

As the code shows here, MicroPost has a datetime column which names pub_date, and this field come from a RSS item pubDate, and this code will lead to the error shows below (on heroku):

```
irb(main):020:0> post=MicroPost.new(:description=>"none", :url=>'url',:title=>"title",:pub_date=>item.pubDate,:tag=>"tag")
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/time.rb:454:in `rfc2822'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:168:in `to_s'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1785:in `attribute_for_inspect'
```

After some googling, i found the solution:http://www.spacebabies.nl/2008/06/16/rails-2-and-rss-parsing-gives-weird-errors/

Although it's Rails2, it still work for me. **just change item.pubDate to item.pubDate.to_s**

Again, can anyone explain what happened here?

ps, item.pubDate is not wrong, in console i can print it, i.e:

```
item.pubDate.class => Time
```