# Random ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid errors on Rails 4 app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, activerecord

My Rails 4 app works fine locally, and also when it's deployed to Heroku in production mode... *until* I access the app from a second client... then after a few clicks I start getting the following strange sequence of errors (see below).

The exact number of clicks varies a little but it always happens eventually... and but only *after* a request from a second client. For example, if I restart the app and only play with it on my phone nothing happens. But as soon as I load a couple pages from my laptop... crash

### Errors

NOTE: These screenshots are with `RAILS_ENV=development` so that the actual errors appear.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure if I'm understanding these errors correctly, but it looks like `?` is not getting properly substituted in the query.

### Environment details

- Rails 4.2
- hosted on Heroku
- Ruby 2.2.x
- MySQL (via ClearDB add-on)

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 2.3.0'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'devise'
gem "paperclip"
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
gem 'foundation-rails'
# Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0', group: :development
gem 'mysql'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'puma'
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'    
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Here's my Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
```

Here's my database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

Here's config/production.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  config.serve_static_files = true

  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET'),
      access_key_id: ENV.fetch('ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      s3_region: ENV.fetch('S3_REGION'),
      s3_host_name: 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
    }
  }


end
```

### Things I tried:

- restarting all dynos (works for a minute but then problem comes back)
- **<s>switching to `gem mysql2` (couldn't even get this running)</s> See answer below**
- switching to `gem puma` (following [this documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#webserver)
- connecting to DB using client (everything seems to work fine)
- confirmed that the parameters of the request are correct a la [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053653/heroku-rails-error-activerecordstatementinvalid) (the request params look fine)
- Reading [this Heroku / Rails 4 documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#heroku-gems) many times

### Similar questions that didn't solve my problem

- [insert to database error on heroku but worked locally, ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155190/insert-to-database-error-on-heroku-but-worked-locally-activerecordstatementin?rq=1)
- [Heroku + Rails Error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053653/heroku-rails-error-activerecordstatementinvalid)
- [Constant 500 Errors on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472247/constant-500-errors-on-heroku)

Comment: Have you tried switching your development environment to MySQL and reproducing the problem there? This is a good idea anyway, developing/testing and deploying with different databases is asking for trouble.

Comment: @muistooshort I'm working on that at this moment. I'm not sure that I'm going to be able to reproduce it locally due to the "second client" aspect of the problem. But I'll try. I agree about matching the environments. This project is a prototype at the moment

Comment: @muistooshort So in the process of setting up the local environment to use MySql, I got the mysql2 gem working... and now the problem doesn't happen. (see my answer below). Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a second crack at deploying with the mysql2 gem, and this time it worked. The secret sauce comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932282/gemloaderror-for-mysql2-gem-but-its-already-in-gemfile)

TLDR;
You need to specify and older version of mysql2 in order to be compatible with *newer* versions of Rails. Yea it's weird.

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
```

After deploying with this gem I can no longer reproduce the problem. I don't understand it, but it worked.

If someone submits an answer that explains what's going on I'll accept it.

Comment: A bit crazy but nothing that works is silly. I don't use MySQL but I have had my share of version number chicanery so I'm not terribly surprised by this.

Answer (score 0):

Came across a similar error, and here's how I resolved it by updating my controllers and models:

Before the update, the controller's index action looked like this

**Before:**

```
def index
    @participants = @events = Participant.all # before update
    format.html { render html: @participants }
    render json: { participants: @participants }
  end
```

I corrected the namespace for the Participant model to match the intended namespace:

**After: Updated**

```
def index
    @participants = @events = Api::V1::Participant.all # Updated this line
    format.html { render html: @participants }
    render json: { participants: @participants }
  end
```

Then in the model,to ensure the correct table name is used, I updated the model by explicitly setting the table name:

```
class Api::V1::Participant < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'participants' # add this line in your model
  belongs_to :event
end
```